# Raven Db Querying dates

Tags: ravendb

Hi can anyone answer me why this linq query wont return by date?

```
DocumentStore store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080/" };
store.Initialize();

using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    bool carExists = session.Query<Car>().Any(c => c.CarId == 1);

    if (!carExists)
    {
        Car myNewCar = new Car
            {
                CarId = 1,
                ManufactureDate = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1),
                Name = "Porshe"
            };

        session.Store(myNewCar);
        session.SaveChanges();
    }

    IQueryable<Car> cars = session.Query<Car>()
            .Where(c => c.ManufactureDate == new DateTime(2010, 1, 1));

    foreach (var car in cars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your index is stale at the second query.  Review [the documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes).

Also, your first query should be a `Load` instead.  Review [the documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/basic-operations/loading-editing-existing-document).

```
DocumentStore store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080/" };
store.Initialize();

using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    bool carExists = session.Load<Car>(1) != null;

    if (!carExists)
    {
        Car myNewCar = new Car
            {
                CarId = 1,
                ManufactureDate = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1),
                Name = "Porshe"
            };

        session.Store(myNewCar);
        session.SaveChanges();
    }

    IQueryable<Car> cars = session.Query<Car>()
            .Customize(x=> x.WaitForNonStaleResults()) // only for testing!
            .Where(c => c.ManufactureDate == new DateTime(2010, 1, 1));

    foreach (var car in cars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it wouldn't be stale on the 2nd run and i get same result then. However if change the linq query to query by id i get a result. I'm looking for an answer to why the date doesn't return a result?

Comment: My bad.  should have been != on the carExists check.  Example updated.  Run it - it works.